# How to avoid repeating http method attribute in WebApi controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have several ASP.NET WebApi controllers with some methods in each. All these methods should be accessible using HTTP POST only. What I'm trying to avoid is explicit [HttpPost] attribute usage for each method. Yep, I'm lazy.
My code looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public void Method1() {  }

[HttpPost]
public void Method2() {  }

...
```

Is there any way to configure route / base controller to access these methods via POST without setting attribute for each method? To have just like this

```
public void Method1() {  }

public void Method2() {  }

...
```

If I try to call method that doesn't have [HttpPost] I'm getting HTTP 405 error.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Web API uses convention over configuration. If you follow the convention to name your actions in the following way...

```
GetXXX
PostXXX
PutXXX
DeleteXXX
```

... you don't have to use the attributes. If the action starts with the appropriate HTTP verb Web API will take care of it.

Comment: My controllers are designed not like REST services but rather than RPC. I would like to keep them protocol agnostic. That's why I prefer not to use 'Post' prefix. Thanks.

Comment: Then you have no other out-of-the-box alternative than using the attributes.